# Timestamp in android studio using Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, timestamp

I'm recreating my iOS app for android using android studio and Kotlin. I'm using Firebase Realtime Database for some functionality on my app and I was making a timestamp for some things in the layout of : "2022-01-01 23:46:37 +0000" as a string for example.

Now I can't seem to figure out of to get this kind of Timestamp format in android studio using Kotlin. what am I missing for what function should be used?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this to get the desired format and it seems to do, not in a nice way, the trick.

```
val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(Date()) + " +0000"
```